# why floating point numbers does not give desired answer?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

hey I am making small C++ program to calculate the value of sin(x) till 7 decimal points but when I calculate **sin(PI/2)** using this program it gives me `0.9999997` rather than `1.0000000` how can I solve this error?
I know of little bit why I'm getting this value as output, question is what should be my approach to solve this logical error?

*here is my code for reference*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
using namespace std;

double sin(double x);
int factorial(int n);
double Pow(double a, int b);

int main()
{
    double x = PI / 2;
    cout << setprecision(7)<< sin(x);
    return 0;
}

double sin(double x)
{
    int n = 1;      //counter for odd powers.
    double Sum = 0; // to store every individual expression.
    double t = 1;   // temp variable to store individual expression
    for ( n = 1; t > 10e-7; Sum += t, n = n + 2)
    {
        // here i have calculated two terms at a time because addition of two consecutive terms is always less than 1.
        t = (Pow(-1.00, n + 1) * Pow(x, (2 * n) - 1) / factorial((2 * n) - 1))
            +
            (Pow(-1.00, n + 2) * Pow(x, (2 * (n+1)) - 1) / factorial((2 * (n+1)) - 1));
    }

    return Sum;
}
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
}
double Pow(double a, int b)
{
    if (b == 1)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return a * Pow(a, b - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user207421: Please do not promiscuously close floating-point questions as duplicates of that question. The problem here is due to errors in integer arithmetic; the `int factorial(int)` function overflows, and changing it to `double factorial(int)` results in the program producing the desired, output, “1”. Jumping to the conclusion that a program that includes floating-point code is wrong because of floating-point behavior is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sin(PI/2) ... it gives me 0.9999997 rather than 1.0000000

For values outside `[-pi/4...+pi/4]` the Taylor's sin/cos series converges slowly and suffers from cancelations of terms and overflow of `int factorial(int n)`<sup>**</sup>.  Stay in the sweet range.

Consider using trig properties `sin(x + pi/2) = cos(x)`, `sin(x + pi) = -sin(x)`, etc. to bring `x` in to the `[-pi/4...+pi/4]` range.

Code uses [remquo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remquo.3.html) ([ref2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remquo)) to find the *remainder and part of quotient*.

```
// Bring x into the -pi/4 ... pi/4  range (i.e. +/- 45 degrees)
// and then call owns own sin/cos function.
double my_wide_range_sin(double x) {
  if (x < 0.0) {
    return -my_sin(-x);
  }
  int quo;
  double x90 = remquo(fabs(x), pi/2, &quo);
  switch (quo % 4) {
    case 0:
      return sin_sweet_range(x90);
    case 1:
      return cos_sweet_range(x90);
    case 2:
      return sin_sweet_range(-x90);
    case 3:
      return -cos_sweet_range(x90);
  }
  return 0.0;
}
```

This implies OP needs to code up a `cos()` function too.

---

<sup>**</sup> Could use `long long` instead of `int` to marginally extend the useful range of `int factorial(int n)` but that only adds a few `x`.  Could use `double`.

A better approach would not use `factorial()` at all, but scale each successive term by `1.0/(n * (n+1))` or the like.

Comment: can you give an explanation or provide a link to understand the functionality of remquo...

Comment: See also [`std::remquo`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remquo)

Comment: @MSalters Added additional good reference.

Answer (score 1):

I see three bugs:

- `10e-7` is `10*10^(-7)` which seems to be 10 times larger than you want.  I think you wanted `1e-7`.
- Your test `t > 10e-7` will become false, and exit the loop, if `t` is still large but negative.  You may want `abs(t) > 1e-7`.
- To get the desired accuracy, you need to get up to `n = 7`, which has you computing `factorial(13)`, which overflows a 32-bit `int`.  (If using gcc you can catch this with `-fsanitize=undefined` or `-ftrapv`.) You can gain some breathing room by using `long long int` which is at least 64 bits, or `int64_t`.

Comment: I don't understand 2nd bug. why it will give true for negative value?

Comment: @setller: Sorry, I said it backwards, fixed now.

Comment: only for that reason I took two consecutive terms.

Comment: @setller: It doesn't help when `x` is large.  Think about `x=5` for instance, the sum of the first two terms is a large negative number. I agree that it doesn't happen to cause a problem for `x = PI/2` but it's still a bug.