# Sinus function using Taylor expansion

Tags: c, floating-point, trigonometry, taylor-series

The teacher asks to remove the pi subtraction cycle in the main function. I don’t know how to write the program so that the correct results will come out for any values.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

double sinus(double x);
int main(void) {
  double a, x;
  scanf("%le", & x);
  a = x;
  while (fabs(x) > 2 * (M_PI)) {
    x = fabs(x) - 2 * (M_PI);
  }
  if (a > 0)
    a = sinus(x);
  else a = (-1) * sinus(x);
  printf("%le", (double) a);
  return 0;
}

double sinus(double x) {
  double sum = 0, h, eps = 1.e-16;
  int i = 2;

  h = x;
  do {
    sum += h;
    h *= -((x * x) / (i * (i + 1)));
    i += 2;
  }
  while (fabs(h) > eps);
  return sum;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the `fmod` function and use it instead of the loop.

Comment: can you give a little more details?

Comment: Note that it would be more logical to put the modulo operation in the `sinus` function. It may be the concern of your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double sinus(double x);
int main(void)
{
    double a,x;
    scanf("%le",&x);
    a=x;
    x=fmod(fabs(x),2*(M_PI));
     if(a>0)
     a=sinus(x);
     else a=(-1)*sinus(x);
    printf("%le",(double)a);
    return 0;}
    
double sinus(double x)
{
  double sum=0, h, eps=1.e-16; int i=2;
 
h=x;
do{
    sum+=h;
    h*=-((x*x)/(i*(i+1)));
    i+=2;}
while( fabs(h)>eps );
return sum;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> … how to write the program so that the correct results will come out for any values.

OP's loop is slow with large `x` and an infinfite loop with very large `x`:

```
while (fabs(x) > 2 * (M_PI)) {
  x = fabs(x) - 2 * (M_PI);
}
```

A *simple*, though not high quality solution, is to use `fmod()` in the function itself. [@Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67115465/sinus-function-using-taylor-expansion-c-programming/68931578#comment118640869_67115465):

```
#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif

double sinus(double x) {
  x = fmod(x, 2*M_PI); // Reduce to [-2*M_PI ... 2*M_PI]
  ...
```

Although function `fmod()` is not expected to inject any [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20928253/2410359), the problem is that `M_PI` (a rational number) is an approximation of [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi), (an irrational number).  Using that value approximation injects error especially `x` near multiplies of π.  This is likely OK for modest quality code.

Good range reduction is a problem as challenging as the trigonometric functions themselves.
See [K.C. Ng's "ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit"](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Ephatak/645/supl/Ng-ArgReduction.pdf) .

---

OP's `sinus()` should use additional range reduction and trigonometric properties to get `x` in range `[-M_PI/4 ... M_PI/4]` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66757952/2410359)) before attempting the power series solution.  Otherwise, convergence is slow and errors accumulate.